# How to serialize and deserialize a hash in Redis (using redis-cpp library)

Tags: c++, redis

I'm using Redis with C++, so I'm using [redis-cpp](https://github.com/tdv/redis-cpp) library to use it with this language. I'm trying to understand RESP protocol. As far as I know, this protocol can serialize and deserialize simple strings, errors, integers, bulk strings and arrays. I want to serialize and deserialize hash too, so I was trying to implement the code but is not as easy as I tough. This library implments some examples, so I was just trying to modify one of these examples:

Here is where data is called:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <redis-cpp/execute.h>

namespace resps = rediscpp::resp::serialization;
namespace respds = rediscpp::resp::deserialization;

auto make_sample_data()
{
    std::ostringstream stream;

    put(stream, resps::array{
            resps::simple_string{"This is a simple string."},
            resps::error_message{"This is an error message."},
            resps::bulk_string{"This is a bulk string."},
            resps::integer{100500},
            resps::array{
                resps::simple_string("This is a simple string in a nested array."),
                resps::bulk_string("This is a bulk string in a nested array.")
            }
        });

    return stream.str();
}
```

I want to add a line similar to the others like: resps::hash(-add here an string, an integer, etc-)

And main function looks like this:

```
{
    try
    {
        auto const data = make_sample_data();
        std::cout << "------------ Serialization ------------" << std::endl;
        std::cout << data << std::endl;

        std::cout << "------------ Deserialization ------------" << std::endl;
        std::istringstream stream{data};
        print_sample_data(stream, std::cout);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception const &e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Serialization function of simple_string, for example, is build like this:

```
#ifndef REDISCPP_RESP_SERIALIZATION_H_
#define REDISCPP_RESP_SERIALIZATION_H_

// STD
#include <cstdint>
#include <forward_list>
#include <ostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

// REDIS-CPP
#include <redis-cpp/detail/config.h>
#include <redis-cpp/resp/detail/marker.h>
#include <redis-cpp/resp/detail/overloaded.h>

namespace rediscpp
{
inline namespace resp
{
namespace serialization
{

template <typename T>
void put(std::ostream &stream, T &&value)
{
    value.put(stream);
}

class simple_string final
{
public:
    simple_string(std::string_view value) noexcept
        : value_{std::move(value)}
    {
    }

    void put(std::ostream &stream)
    {
        stream << detail::marker::simple_string
               << value_
               << detail::marker::cr
               << detail::marker::lf;
    }

private:
    std::string_view value_;
};
```

And deserialization for same function is build like this:

```
#ifndef REDISCPP_RESP_DESERIALIZATION_H_
#define REDISCPP_RESP_DESERIALIZATION_H_

// STD
#include <cstdint>
#include <istream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

// REDIS-CPP
#include <redis-cpp/detail/config.h>
#include <redis-cpp/resp/detail/marker.h>

namespace rediscpp
{
inline namespace resp
{
namespace deserialization
{

[[nodiscard]]
auto get_mark(std::istream &stream)
{
    switch (stream.get())
    {
    case detail::marker::simple_string :
        return detail::marker::simple_string;
    case detail::marker::error_message :
        return detail::marker::error_message;
    case detail::marker::integer :
        return detail::marker::integer;
    case detail::marker::bulk_string :
        return detail::marker::bulk_string;
    case detail::marker::array :
        return detail::marker::array;
    default:
        break;
    }
    throw std::invalid_argument{
            "[rediscpp::resp::deserialization::get_mark] "
            "Bad input format."
        };
}

template <typename T>
[[nodiscard]]
T get(std::istream &stream)
{
    return {stream};
}

class simple_string final
{
public:
    simple_string(std::istream &stream)
    {
        std::getline(stream, value_);
        value_.pop_back(); // removing '\r' from string
    }

    [[nodiscard]]
    std::string_view get() const noexcept
    {
        return value_;
    }

private:
    std::string value_;
};
```

How can I add hash as a type and build the functions in serialize and deserialize as it was done with simple_string? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What's exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want to save an unordered_map into a HASH or vice versa?

Comment: Hi @for_stack ! I want to serialize and deserialize a struct, an object itself with different fields.